# How to use a rails helper in a PDF template inside services layer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a PDF template and I need to use a view helper method inside a HTML file that is in the services folder to generate the PDF. However, when I try to use the default view helpers, I get an exception that the method doesn't exist.

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `helper_method' for #<#<Class:0x000000000e309bd0>:0x000000000e3a0350>
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: You'll need to show a bit more code for context. `helper_method` is used in controllers to make methods available inside views. It's not supposed to be used in views directly. What do you mean "HTML file"? Do you mean an HTML view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your module methods work as they were class methods by using

> module_function :method

The code looks like this:

```
module Helper
  def helper_method; end

  module_function :helper_method
end
```

Then in your html.erb you do this:

```
<% Helper.helper_method %>
```